# UIlabel NSMutableAttributedString second line not visible upon line break

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I am trying to create a `UILabel` which contains two texts of different fonts where one `NSMutableAttributedString` sits vertically on top of the other. Upon attempting to insert a line break via swift's `\n` I found that the appended string disappears. I have tried a variety of `lineBreakMode`s with no result (with and without `\n`) along with ensuring the frame isnt constricting the texts visibility by setting a large `maximumLineHeight`.

I should also mention that according to Apple's documentation when setting `UILabel.attributedText` to any `NSAttributedText` instance

> When the label has an attributed string value, the system ignores the textColor, font, textAlignment, lineBreakMode, and lineBreakStrategy properties. Set the foregroundColor, font, alignment, lineBreakMode, and lineBreakStrategy properties in the attributed string instead.

Here is some of the code simplified for the sake of the question (I have also tried calling `.sizeTofit()` after setting the labels `attributedText` as well as setting different `.lineBreakStrategy`s)

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

let totalVisitsString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(visitLogs.count)\n", attributes: [.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25), .paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle])

totalVisitsString.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Total visits", attributes: [.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]))

totalVisitsLabel.attributedText = totalVisitsString
```

the label itself:

```
var totalVisitsLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return label
    }()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default your label's `numberOfLines` is 1. You never change it so that is what you get.

Comment: Lol so much effort put into this question. Thought that since attributed text was set it would ignore the property suppose I shouldve tried it first hahah. Im prolly going to delete this question thank you @matt

Answer (score 1):

Labels when created are defaulted to 1 line. You'll need to set the number of lines to 0 (unlimited) or whatever number you want to max it at.

```
var totalVisitsLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()
```